# Isometric position multi dimensional array sorting where z property are defines how many pixels should it be lifted upwards

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, html5-canvas, isometric

I have an array of isometric objects that has x,y,z properties. I'm trying to sort the array for rendering purposes (first index rendered first). I tried to sort the array using the code below but it's inaccurate.

```
this.objects.sort((a,b) => {
    return ((a.x + a.y) / 2) - ((b.x + b.y) / 2)
});
this.objects.sort((a,b) => {
    return a.z - b.z
})
```

[image: screenshot]

and when I try this code

```
this.objects.sort((a,b) => {
    if(a.z > b.z) return 1;
    if(((a.x + a.y) / 2) > ((b.x + b.y) / 2)) return 1;
    return -1
});
```

this happens:

[image]

Is there a way to sort the array so it renders properly?

```
for(var obj of this.objects) {
    if(!this.sprites[obj.sprite] || !this.sprites[obj.sprite].loaded) {
        continue;
    }
    var centralPoint = obj.centralPoint();
    this.ctx.drawImage(this.sprites[obj.sprite].image,centralPoint.x - this.sprites[obj.sprite].offset[0], centralPoint.y - this.sprites[obj.sprite].offset[1]);
}
```

My Isometric Object:

```
    function IsoObject(main,sprite,x,y,z = 0,height = 0, scale = 1,onClick = function() {}) {
        this.main = main;
        if(!main.sprites[sprite]) main.addSprite(sprite,sprite);
        this.sprite = sprite;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        this.scale = scale;
        this.height = height;
        this.onclick = onClick;
        return this;
    }

    IsoObject.prototype.centralPoint = function() {
        var x = this.x * this.main.increment.x - (this.y * this.main.increment.x);
        var y = this.y * this.main.increment.y - this.z + (this.x * this.main.increment.y);
        return {
            x: x,
            y: y
        }
    }
```

this.main.increment:

```
this.increment = {
    x: this.tileSize * Math.sin(this.angle * (Math.PI / 180)),
    y: this.tileSize * Math.cos(this.angle * (Math.PI / 180))
}
```

Object positions:

```
0: "x:4.999000000000007,y:4.136499999999993,z:0"
1: "x:1,y:3,z:0"
2: "x:4,y:3,z:-1"
3: "x:2,y:4,z:-1"
4: "x:1,y:3,z:39"
5: "x:1,y:3,z:40"
```

if you see, z property is not the same as x and y, z property defines how many pixels should be the image translated upwards.

**EDIT**

This sorting kinda works but still inaccurate

[image]

```
this.objects.sort((a,b) => {
    var ac = a.centralPoint();
    var bc = b.centralPoint();
    return (ac.x + ac.y + a.z) - (bc.x + bc.y + b.z)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take `z` first then `y` and at last `x`.

```
this.objects.sort((a, b) =>
    a.z - b.z ||
    a.y - b.y ||
    a.x - b.x
);
```

Comment: maybe it would help, if you add the dimentions in the image. or add some randering code here.

Comment: I actually tried creating my own isometric engine, i'll edit the post and try to put it

Comment: maybe a change of `z` is helping. this sorts now the last to top.

Comment: Hello @Nina Scholz , I updated my post again maybe it will make sense that z sorting doesn't work well

Comment: please try the above.